# How do I auto generate domain & range? Anyone know why my data is not showing up?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm able to generate my domain and range if I hard code it, but I am interested in auto generating it. In my code I use d3.extent and d3.max in domain/range to do this, but it doesn't generate it.

Also, anyone know why my data is not showing up?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Line Chart</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="layout">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // one-stop-shop
        var dataset = "avgVehicleTripLengthMiles.json";

        // dimensions
        var margin = {
            top: 30,
            right: 20,
            bottom: 30,
            left: 50
        },
        width = 800 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        // create scales for axes 
        var x_scale = d3.scaleLinear();
        var y_scale = d3.scaleLinear();

        // format range for axes
        x_scale.range([margin.left, width - margin.right]); // 

        y_scale.range([height - margin.top, margin.bottom]); // height - margin.top, margin.bottom

        // generate path by returning data values; .x is x accessor
        var path = d3.line()
            .x(function (d) {
            return x_scale(d.year);
        })
            .y(function (d) {
            return y_scale(d.miles);
        })

        // dimensions of svg canvas
        var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        // Get the data
        d3.json(dataset, function (error, data) {
            if (error) throw error;

        // format domain for scales
        x_scale.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
            return d[0]; // took out d.year
        }));


        y_scale.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
            return d[1]; // took out d.miles
        })]);

        // add the path to the svg canvas
        svg.append("path")
            .attr("d", path(data))
            .attr("fill", "none")
            .attr("stroke", "red")
            .attr("stroke-width", 2);

        // create axis and place scaling on it
        var x_axis = d3.axisBottom().scale(x_scale).ticks(5);

        var y_axis = d3.axisLeft().scale(y_scale).ticks(5);

        // add the axes with the scales to the svg canvas
        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "xAxis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height - margin.bottom) + ")")
            .call(x_axis);

        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "yAxis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + ",0)")
            .call(y_axis);

        // create title label
        var title = d3.select("body")
            .append("h4")
            .attr("x", width / 2)
            .attr("y", height)
            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .text("Avg. Vehicle Trip Length per Mile");

        // create text label for x-axis
        svg.append("text")
            .attr("x", width / 2)
            .attr("y", height)
            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .text("Year");

        // create text label for y-axis
        svg.append("text")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
            .attr("x", (-130 - margin.left / 2))
            .attr("y", (height / 2) - 130)
            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .text("Miles");
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In the d3.extent callback, why are you using: `return d[0];` instead of `return d.year;`?

Comment: @JohnThompson I had return d.year; beforehand, but changed it to return d[0]; since I automatically wanted it to get the header in the .csv file, versus me hard-coding. Is what I'm doing wrong? What do you suggest?

Comment: Ohhhh.. if you automatically want the header then you can use `data.columns[0]`. Note, this will only work in d3 version-4, which it appears that you are using :)

Comment: @Laura - Did my reply help answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear what your data structure is. Keep in mind that `d3.extent` along with `d3.min` and `d3.max` takes 2 arguments - the `data` (which in this case is the JSON array) and optionally the `accessor` which is a function that you can think of as being applied via a `map` operation on each element of the `data` array to generate a new array on whom the `extent`/`min` or `max` operation is performed.

Your current code is trying to pass in `d[0]` for each element in data to create the new array that is fed into `d3.extent`, but this is undefined since `d[0]` is trying to look for a key of `0` in each array of your JSON data (likely of the format `{year: 1999, miles:50}` ). As you can clearly see, invoking `d[0]` on this element results in an error.

Here is a toy example to illustrate this more clearly:

```
data = [{x:1, y:2},{x:5,y:5}]
console.log(d3.extent(dat, function(d) {return d.x;}));
```

**Output:** `[1, 5]`

The following should work for you:

```
// format domain for scales
x_scale.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
    return d.year;
}));

y_scale.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
    return d.miles; 
}));
```